# jQuery prev next elements

Tags: jquery

My issue in jQuery code. I have this code [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pokrowsky/errdcsnL/2/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#clickinput1").click(function (evt) {
     $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
  });
});
```

Before click on button, input is disable and have dark background. I need, when click on button input be enabled(this work) and background change on white color or none. I cannot make this. Please help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could be done simply using `.css("background-color","white")` like :

```
$(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).css("background-color","white").focus();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickinput1").click(function(evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).css("background-color", "white").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="customername" class="input" value="" disabled />

<div style="float:right;cursor:pointer;margin:2px 0 0 0px;" id="clickinput1">
  <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/simplicio/128x128/document_edit.png" />button
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, its work. Its a simple, i just write 
$(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).css("background-color:#fff").focus(); 
I write css property wrong. Thank you for big help

Answer (score 1):

You are giving css as `$("#white").css("background-color:#fff");`. That's not the right way to defince css in jquery. It should be `$("#white").css("background-color","#fff");`. Another thing is you haven't given id as `white` to any of the element. Changing all these will solve your issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickinput1").click(function(evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
    $("#white").css("background-color", "#fff");
  });
});
```

```css
.input {
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  font: 18px Calibri;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

body {
  background-color: #006699;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="customername" class="input" value="" id="white" disabled />
<div style="float:right;cursor:pointer;margin:2px 0 0 0px;" id="clickinput1"><img src="img/edit.png" />button</div>
```

Even we don't need to define any id. This can simply be done like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#clickinput1").click(function(evt) {
    $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus().css("background-color", "#fff");
   
  });
});
```

```css
.input {
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 20px;
  width: 250px;
  font: 18px Calibri;
  margin-top: 1px;
}

body {
  background-color: #006699;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="customername" class="input" value="" id="white" disabled />
<div style="float:right;cursor:pointer;margin:2px 0 0 0px;" id="clickinput1"><img src="img/edit.png" />button</div>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki read my answer carefully I already mentioned that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickinput1").click(function (evt) {
        $(this).hide().prev("input[disabled]").prop("disabled", false).focus();
        $(".input").css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```